# Python regex search pattern or string in reverse direction

Tags: regex, python-3.x, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I'm trying to mine a database of strings for a certain pattern. I want to look for a pattern in both the forward and reverse direction. I attempted creating two capture groups, however, as the pattern grows larger, reversing it is not easy and might introduce errors. I thought about creating the reverses of my sequence, however, I'm not sure how to integrate it into my list of rules:

```
re.findall(regex, v) or re.findall(regex, v[::-1])
```

I also want to add more conditions like if the first 10 letters contain a certain letter, how can I do that without cluttering my code?

```
import re
database={'key', 'MSCPFSPKQPGFGHFREPTTRSSVAKVIERNSGALIVFGGAAACVVAGWKVRGYLTDRQLSQL'}
regex = r'([A-Z]{3}[Y|W|F|I|H][A-Z]P[^YFWHI]{4}[Y|W|F|I|H][A-Z]{3})|([A-Z]{3}[Y|W|F|I|H][^YFWHI]{4}P[A-Z][Y|W|F|I|H][A-Z]{3})'

for k,v in database.items():
    rules = [re.findall(regex, v), 1 < len(v) < 200, len(re.findall(r'W',v))<4]
    if all(rules):
        print(re.findall(regex, v))
        print('%s' %k)
        print('%s' %v)
        print('%s' %len(v))
        print('\n')
```

Comment: why reverse your string? The pattern is already reversed

Comment: yes as I said, I don't want to reverse the pattern like this, "as the pattern grows larger, reversing it is not easy and might introduce errors", I need alternatives

Answer (score 0):

I think what @Onyambu was saying is just reverse the string if no match and search for the pattern again.

```
import re
database={'key', 'MSCPFSPKQPGFGHFREPTTRSSVAKVIERNSGALIVFGGAAACVVAGWKVRGYLTDRQLSQL'}
regex = r'([A-Z]{3}[Y|W|F|I|H][A-Z]P[^YFWHI]{4}[Y|W|F|I|H][A-Z]{3})|([A-Z]{3}[Y|W|F|I|H][^YFWHI]{4}P[A-Z][Y|W|F|I|H][A-Z]{3})'

for k,v in database.items():
    rules = [re.findall(regex, v), 1 < len(v) < 200, len(re.findall(r'W',v))<4]
    if all(rules):
        print(re.findall(regex, v))
        print('%s' %k)
        print('%s' %v)
        print('%s' %len(v))
        print('\n')
    else:
        # reverse your string
        v = v[::-1]
        rules = [re.findall(regex, v), 1 < len(v) < 200, len(re.findall(r'W',v))<4]
        if all(rules):
            print(re.findall(regex, v))
            print('%s' %k)
            print('%s' %v)
            print('%s' %len(v))
            print('\n')
```